# MYsql : select one id from multiple id which have multiple value

Tags: mysql, select

```
+------+---------+
| id   | object  |
+------+---------+
| 1    |    1    |
| 1    |    2    |
| 1    |    3    |
| 2    |    1    |
| 2    |    3    |
| 2    |    4    |
| 3    |    5    |
| 3    |    3    |
| 3    |    4    |
+------+---------+
```

i want to select id , that have object 1,2,3 but the result is just id = 1, ignore the other id if that not have object 1,2,3 . 
ignore id 2 that just have object 1 and 3, and ignore id 3 that just have object 3.

thanks for help, master.

Comment: What did I just read?

Comment: This question ticks every box.

Answer (score 3):

A `GROUP BY`/`HAVING` can help you find id's where all 3 exist;

```
SELECT id 
FROM Table1
WHERE object IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT object) = 3
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6b5f/2).

Basically what it does is get all rows that have an `object` equal to 1, 2, or 3, and return id's where the number of distinct object values is 3.